# Publishing to the @types organaization in npm

Tags: typescript, github, npm, definitelytyped

Is submitting a Pull Request to DefinitelyTyped\DefinitelyTyped in github still the preferred way to publish type definitions to the @types organization in npm, or could you put your own github repository into the @types organization somehow?

Comment: You have to publish to `DefinitelyTyped` if you want to use `@types`, however you can set the typings for the project itself if you have the ability to update it. You can also define typings for third party modules locally without publishing them.